# What do malware authors using android root exploits go after?

Tags: android, rootkits

I know there has been a lot of discussion on rooting on the internet and even on stack exchange.

What I want to ask here is not how rooting works - assuming the root exploit as a black box, what does the malware author really want to go after on an android device, once a root exploit is used successfully?

I ask in reference to the android architecture - what are their prime targets?

Comment: Anything that gives them a 5-finger discount. The overhead's so low. So, personal information, financial information, any account they can access for free while you pay for it, even the raw computing power of your device.

Answer (score 4):

Mobile malware is after the same thing as regular malware it's just on a different platform.

We use our phones to do everything from email, banking, social media, etc.  Security tokens are stored in these devices for all kinds of different applications, and possibly web-sites.  The average user doesn't take mobile security seriously.  Try `3333` or `6666` on a friend's iPhone some time.

Access to email can give more than enough information to start taking over accounts, and could lead to identity theft.  Even if they're not after your identity they can still just be the annoying malicious malware.  [Ransom-ware](http://www.welivesecurity.com/2015/09/10/aggressive-android-ransomware-spreading-in-the-usa/) is becoming popular on Android.  Maybe they just want to spam a [bunch of ads](http://www.zdnet.com/article/new-android-adware-ensnares-thousands-of-apps-cannot-be-removed/) through your apps.

Nowadays you need to treat your phone like you would your laptop/desktop because they've now become equivalent.

Comment: Another attack vector could be to automatically perform app-store purchases.